# Изменение цвета маркера

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть метки, которые берутся из JSON файла:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 0, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.674244, 23.737227]},"properties":{ "hintContent": "Казановского 11"},"status":"free"},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 1, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.682719, 23.831406]},"properties":{ "hintContent": "Виленская 6"},"status":"free"},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 2, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.656318, 23.849840]},"properties":{ "hintContent": "Янки Купалы 80/2"},"status":"busy"},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 3, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.622756, 23.814832]},"properties":{ "hintContent": "Великая Ольшанка 15"},"status":"busy"},
    {"type": "Feature", "id": 4, "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [53.685108, 23.839967]},"properties":{ "hintContent": "Ожешко 22"},"status":"free"}
  ]
}
```

Через `objectManager` добавляются на карту:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [53.677850, 23.829484],
            zoom: 10
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            clusterize: false,
            gridSize: 32,
        });
    objectManager.objects.options.set('preset', 'islands#blueAutoIcon');

    $.ajax({
        url: "data.json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        objectManager.add(data);
        var maxLat = 0,
            maxLon = 0,
            minLat = 100,
            minLon = 100;
        objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
            var lat = object.geometry.coordinates[0],
                lon = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
            maxLat = (lat <= maxLat) ? maxLat : lat;
            maxLon = (lon <= maxLon) ? maxLon : lon;
            minLat = (lat >= minLat) ? minLat : lat;
            minLon = (lon >= minLon) ? minLon : lon;
        }, myMap);
        myMap.setBounds([[minLat, minLon], [maxLat, maxLon]]);
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
}
```

У меток есть статус.
Как сделать метки со статусом `free` зеленого цвета, а метки со статусом `busy` - красного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете либо сразу занести в JSON нужные пресеты в `properties` объектов, либо делать это по условию при добавлении на карту:

```
  if (object.status == "free") {
      objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(object.id, {
        preset: 'islands#greenAutoIcon'
      });
  }
  else {
      objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(object.id, {
        preset: 'islands#blueAutoIcon'
      });
  }
```

Пример полностью вот:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
      center: [53.677850, 23.829484],
      zoom: 10
    }, {
      searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
      clusterize: false,
      gridSize: 32,
    });

  data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 0,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [53.674244, 23.737227]
        },
        "properties": {
          "hintContent": "Казановского 11"
        },
        "status": "free"
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 1,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [53.682719, 23.831406]
        },
        "properties": {
          "hintContent": "Виленская 6"
        },
        "status": "free"
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 2,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [53.656318, 23.849840]
        },
        "properties": {
          "hintContent": "Янки Купалы 80/2"
        },
        "status": "busy"
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 3,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [53.622756, 23.814832]
        },
        "properties": {
          "hintContent": "Великая Ольшанка 15"
        },
        "status": "busy"
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": 4,
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [53.685108, 23.839967]
        },
        "properties": {
          "hintContent": "Ожешко 22"
        },
        "status": "free"
      }
    ]
  };
  objectManager.add(data);
  var maxLat = 0,
    maxLon = 0,
    minLat = 100,
    minLon = 100;
  objectManager.objects.each(function(object) {
    var lat = object.geometry.coordinates[0],
      lon = object.geometry.coordinates[1];
    maxLat = (lat <= maxLat) ? maxLat : lat;
    maxLon = (lon <= maxLon) ? maxLon : lon;
    minLat = (lat >= minLat) ? minLat : lat;
    minLon = (lon >= minLon) ? minLon : lon;
    if (object.status == "free") {
      objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(object.id, {
        preset: 'islands#greenAutoIcon'
      });
    } else {
      objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(object.id, {
        preset: 'islands#blueAutoIcon'
      });
    }

  }, myMap);
  myMap.setBounds([
    [minLat, minLon],
    [maxLat, maxLon]
  ]);

  myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```